# C# equivalent to Java's Runtime.freeMemory(), Runtime.totalMemory(), Runtime.maxMemory()

Tags: java, c#

I would like to know how the following methods in Java are used in C#.

```
Runtime.freeMemory()

Runtime.totalMemory()

Runtime.maxMemory()
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc?view=net-6.0

Comment: Try reading this docs on GC Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

```
// Java
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.printf("MEM: %,d/%,d/%,d\n", rt.freeMemory(), rt.totalMemory(), rt.maxMemory());
```

```
// C#
GCMemoryInfo memoryInfo = GC.GetGCMemoryInfo(GCKind.Any);
long maxMemory = memoryInfo.TotalAvailableMemoryBytes;
long totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
long freeMemory = maxMemory - totalMemory;
Console.WriteLine($"MEM: {freeMemory:#,##0}/{totalMemory:#,##0}/{maxMemory:#,##0}");
```

Any problems with this method?

Comment: and what kinf od a problem do you expect?